# Change scrollbar in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, scrollbar

I've achieved the desired design for the scrollbar using the following:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 12px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
    border-radius: 8px;
    background-color: #999;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 8px;
    background-color: #666;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
}
```

As it can be seen above the changes are of course not for Internet Explorer, where I could just do for the moment the following:

```
body {
    -ms-scrollbar-base-color: #999;
    -ms-scrollbar-track-color: #999;
    -ms-scrollbar-face-color: #666;
    -ms-scrollbar-arrow-color: #999;
}
```

I want to know if is possible to recreate the same design present on Chrome in IE. Below are printscreens with the scrollbar, first from Chrome, second from Internet Explorer.

[image] [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunatelly there is no cross browser way to style scrollbar with CSS. But you can try next JavaScript custom scrollbar plugins (mostly jQuery): [jQuery Scrollbar](http://gromo.github.io/jquery.scrollbar/), [jScrollPane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/), [mCustomScrollbar](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/), [perfect-scrollbar](http://noraesae.github.com/perfect-scrollbar/), [slimScroll](http://rocha.la/jQuery-slimScroll/), [baron](https://github.com/Diokuz/baron/) or [NiceScroll](http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll/). There are more custom scrollbars available, but they are less functional/well-known.

Answer (score 1):

I have use this : http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/ this work on IE and it is very easy to use :) Enjoy !